# How can I end my Javafx tic-tac-toe?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I made tic-tac-toe game using javafx. I'm new in java and I tried to make way to end game after winning or draw. There is no need to check if winning or losing or anything. I want put that text to end when you can't continue playing. I tried use array but I have no idea what to do.

Here is my code:

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import javafx.application.Application;
  import javafx.scene.Scene;
  import javafx.scene.control.Button;
  import javafx.scene.control.Label;
  import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
  import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
  import javafx.scene.text.Font;
  import javafx.stage.Stage;

  public class ticTacToe extends Application {

private boolean turn;
private int[][] locations;

public RistinollaSovellus() {
    turn = true;
    locations = new int[3][3];

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(ticTacToe.class);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {
    boolean endGame = false;

    BorderPane layout = new BorderPane();

    Label text = new Label("Turn: X");
    text.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 40));
    layout.setTop(text);

    GridPane array = new GridPane();
    if (!endGame) {

        for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= 3; y++) {
                Button btn = new Button(" ");
                btn.setFont(Font.font("Monospaced", 40));
                array.add(nappi, x, y);
                locations[x][y] = 0;

                btn.setOnAction((event) -> {
                    if (btn.getText().equals(" ")) {

                        if (turn) {
                            btn.setText("X");
                            text.setText("Turn: O");
                            turn = false;

                        } else if (!turn) {
                            btn.setText("O");
                            text.setText("Turn: X");
                            turn = true;
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    layout.setCenter(array);

    Scene showing = new Scene(layout);

    window.setScene(showing);
    window.show();
}

  }
```

Comment: Use a counter to keep up with the number of moves made. Once the number of moves made gets to 9 end the game

Comment: @SedrickJefferson, What happens if someone gets 3 in a row before all 9 turns are used?

Comment: You could use a for loop since you know the max number of moves a game has. You could also use a while loop. Break the loop on any win condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument passed to `btn.setOnAction()` is an event listener and its logic is executed each time a user clicks the button.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ButtonBase.html#setOnAction-javafx.event.EventHandler-

On a button click you want to check if the grid contains a valid tic-tac-toe configuration. To do this, you need to expand the listener and use the `location` array to check the current state of all buttons on the grid.

Once a valid combination of cells is found, you call `Platform.exit()` to stop the application.

**EDIT:** The `x` and `y` loop variables should start at 0 and go up to 2, otherwise an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown. The first index of an array is 0, not 1.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you mean but I think if you implemented the game this far like if its working as it should then it'll be really easy for you to figure out how to end it.

See you can do many things here if any player wins you can just show an alert that player x won and give an option to either quit or restart the application all over, in case of a tie you can do the same.

Technically call the `stop()` method to stop all the processes and to end the game

Comment: Simply calling `stop()` does not work, because _Application#stop_ contains an empty body and does nothing but expecting your application to override it.